# Form fill Submit/Redirecting, but not Refreshing (current page), without jQuery or Ajax, in PHP

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to fill a form and Submit & Redirecting, but without refreshing the current page; without using jQuery or Ajax, in PHP.

I know how to do it by using jQuery, but the thing I was wondering is that why does the page refresh happens (on current page) and how to submit/redirect without the happening of the page refresh. In short everything happening in html/php

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer **No**

`PHP` is a serverside language and therefor cannot be used to trigger client side events without using some form of javascript/jquery and websockets (or keep polling with ajax to the php script).

But what you can do is submit the form and redirect back to the current page. (The page will be refreshed)

Comment: and if javascript/jquery/websockets are blocked or aren't allowed, then what is the solution?

Comment: @cock For as far as i know nothing.